# Access a variable given by the user inside the req.url

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a todo app using Node.js, but I faced this problem: I can't access the entered number after the URL which represents the item id.

```
// -------------- DELETING ------------------
var id;
if (method == "DELETE" && route == "/${id}"){
    if(todoList.length == id) {
    todoList.splice(((id)-1),1);
    res.end();
    }
    else{
        res.end("item not fount in the array");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> i can't access the entered number after the url which represents the
> item id

You must explain the question more clearly with more information to provide a straightforward answer. According question and given code,

You misunderstand entirely the basic concepts also in Nodejs.

There is no route option in inside the request object and no way to access the ID using the parameters of a resource in the given URL if you are not using an express.

Instead, you can split the URL and find the id.

```
const id = req.url.split("/")[req.url.split("/").length - 1];
```

Here is the way I used when I developed an application from scratch but,

---

If you are using the express library no need for the above boilerplate code just use,

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//Handle incoming delete requests.
app.delete("/api/v1/items/:itemId", (req, res) => {
    const itemId == req.params.itemId;
});

//Listening to the client request
app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 3000...");
});
```

Comment: thank you I'm just new node.js leaner and i have a task to do this using node.js without express so thank you it helped me a lot